# Driving Relay to switch 6A

Tags: relay, gpio, amperage

It's been many years since I looked at hardware.  I want to build a circuit; a [16 pin GPIO](http://za.rs-online.com/webdocs/137e/0900766b8137eed4.pdf) that switches a [5V Coil, 6A relay](http://za.rs-online.com/webdocs/12d2/0900766b812d269f.pdf) to switch a [6A, 15V Peltier](http://za.rs-online.com/webdocs/091a/0900766b8091add7.pdf).  So working from the Peltier, I found a relay that can switch it on, I hopefully (power supplied using [PC Power supply](http://za.rs-online.com/webdocs/13f4/0900766b813f4ae4.pdf)) - If not, then I'll need to fix this before going on.

Now my question is, can the GPIO chip switch the relay?

What I could find in the datasheet is that the GPIO output current on a pin is 25mA (Page 27 of [16 pin GPIO](http://za.rs-online.com/webdocs/137e/0900766b8137eed4.pdf)) and the relay requires 1A? (Page 1 of [5V Coil, 6A relay](http://za.rs-online.com/webdocs/12d2/0900766b812d269f.pdf)) - or is it 6A?

Comment: All you need is to drive a switching device to the relay coil. The best way is to drive a gate MOSFET by your GPIO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to focus on the coil data itself and not the contact data for the relay.  6A will be right against your limit for switching your load.  15V is well under 125VDC so you should be fine.  Just something to consider.

At 5VDC, the coil has a resistance of 147 Ohms which means it will require ~35mA to switch the relay.  So the relay does not require 1A to switch.  It has a power of 170 milliwatts from 5 to 24VDC.

By looking at the GPIO chip, we can observe that the maximum source or sink current by any output pins is 25mA.  This probably will not be enough to swtich the relay on and off.  Therefore, you will need some type of amplification to make your circuit working in between the microprocessor and the relay.  I will leave that up to you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an [ULN2003A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2003a.pdf) and a 12V relay, since you have 12V available.

One chip will easily drive 7 relays of that type (12V 848 ohm coil).

[image]

Tie COM to 12V (this is important!!- it tames the relay inductance so it doesn't break down the drivers) and don't forget to provide a ground line that does not require relay current to pass through the ground connections of your IO expander chip.

Do note the electrical life at 6A- only 60,000 operations at 6A so if you run at full current and 1 cycle every 10 seconds it will last only about a week when run 24/7 (or half that if you're using the N.C. contact). Life driven with the normal type of circuit will typically be a bit less again because drop-out is slowed by the diode clamp.

For this current and voltage, usually a low Rds(on) MOSFET or DC SSR would be preferable.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information!  I appreciate the time you took.

Answer (score 0):

The GPIO spec says about 0.5V with 8mA.  1A is the max you can put it the coil and not damage it.  The coil is 147 Ohms so needs about 34mA when it is on.  You will need some kind of buffer between the GPIO and relay coil.